Define quasi-projective varieties in similar manner like manifolds?
In Fulton's book about algebraic curves, he defines the quasi-projective varieties to be open subsets of a hybrid variety (an irreducible algebraic set in $\mathbb{P}^{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{A}^m$). I found this definition unintuitive. After the exercises, I realized that there is a covering of quasi-projective varieties by affine varieties and the quasi-projective varieties are 'locally affine'. My question is: Can we define the quasi-projective varieties in a similar way as we define smooth manifolds? For example, is the following 'definition' for quasi-projective varieties correct: A quasi-projective variety is a topological space $V$, with an 'affine atlas' $\left\lbrace (V_{\lambda}, \varphi_{\lambda}) \right\rbrace_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$:

$\varphi_{\lambda}: V_{\lambda} \rightarrow A_{\lambda} \subset \mathbb{A}^{n_{\lambda}}$ is a homeomorphism where $A_{\lambda}$ is an affine variety with Zariski topology.

For each pair of $\lambda, \mu \in \Lambda$, $\varphi_{\lambda}(V_{\lambda} \cap V_{\mu}), \varphi_{\mu}(V_{\lambda} \cap V_{\mu})$ are subvarieties of $A_{\lambda}, A_{\mu}$ respectively, and that $\varphi_\mu ^{-1} \circ \varphi_\lambda$ and $\varphi_\lambda ^{-1} \circ \varphi_\mu$ are polynomial maps between affine varieties.


It should be noted that by 'affine variety', I mean irreducible algebraic sets in some $\mathbb{A}^n$, to avoid circular definition.
I wonder if this 'definition' makes sense and how I can prove the equivalence between this 'definition' and the one in Fulton's book. (I find the latter hard as constructing the embedding from nowhere seems impossible, perhaps I should require the atlas to be finite?)

I think the natural direction to go with this line of thought is schemes.

This way you will not get quasiprojective varieties in the usual sense, just think about the nonseparated example analogous to the "line with two origins" (it is somewhere in Hartshorne).

Even if you assume separatedness (or even completeness), having an embedding into projective space is an extra property.

You can certainly define abstract algebraic varieties in the way you suggest.
However, as noted in the comments, this is strictly more general than quasiprojective varieties:

Quasiprojective varieties are always quasicompact, irreducible, and separated.
These three properties are global properties, so merely having a locally affine atlas does not help.
For example, any infinite discrete set can be equipped with a locally affine atlas, but it is impossible to realise it as a quasiprojective variety.

Projective varieties are complete, but not every complete (abstract algebraic) variety is projective.
In fact, there is a famous (counter)example due to Hironaka of a 3-dimensional smooth complete variety that does not embed in any projective space.


Incidentally, there is a simpler definition of quasiprojective variety that is equivalent to the one you cite: a quasiprojective variety is any irreducible closed subset of any open subset of any projective space.
The key observation is that $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$ can be embedded as a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^{n m + n + m}$: this is the Segre embedding.
Thus, mixed cartesian products of projective and affine spaces are quasiprojective in this simpler sense, and it is not hard to see that any open or irreducible closed subset of a quasiprojective variety in this sense is also quasiprojective.

Hi, thanks for the answer! I appreciate the hint on the necessary topological conditions that need to be placed on the quasi-projective varieties. However, although I am aware of the equivalent definition as proved in Fulton's book, I found that a little bit intuitive, as I am not sure why we should generalize projective varieties to quasi-projective ones. I was wondering if there is a set of topological properties (together with the atlas) that characterize the quasi-projective varieties.
